# Nested Recyclerview using TalkBack seems to skip elements and not read things in an order displayed

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, talkback, accessibility

**Summary:**

When using talkback with nested recyclerview using the [swiping](https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/6006598?hl=en) the scrolling seems to hop as in skip complete rows and sometimes not scroll all the way to the right.  Keep in mind this only happens when both the width of the nested recyclerview is larger than the screen.  I included a video of me just swiping to the right and you can see the issues.  Weirdness like this is happening on my work project as well.

**Video**

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fUT4F0CaD34lLVdELBoBK3EPZ4PeNmMy/view?usp=sharing

Keep in mind there is 7 in each row and sometimes it skips the 7th.  Also sometimes it just skips to a completely new roll or scroll weird.  On my work project I have seen it skip rows as well.

**Details:**

I recreated it on a simple example online of nested recyclerview.  I simplified it as much as I could here
https://github.com/DavidCorrado/NestedRecyclerview

I tried what other articles suggested which it seems to me everyone just eventually gave up

```
nestedScrollingEnabled
descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
focusableInTouchMode="true"
descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
```

**Question:**

Is this just broken or is there any work arounds for nested recyclerview?

Comment: I have the same problem.. although it works perfectly when the items are traversed in reverse. Moving forward after the last horizontal RecyclerView item will skip some items in the vertical RecyclerView, seemingly having to do with the autoscroll. Some interesting research over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48133174/android-accessibility-talkback-traverses-elements-in-wrong-order but sadly don't have time to dig in much right now.

Comment: Was this issue fixed for you Siena.  Now I cant replicate at all
Reported this bug and it appears to not happen anymore

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/223351049